# python word from list

Tags: python, if-statement

I created a small program that searches for a specific word in a list. It seems to work, but I'd like it to also print out the word that it found.

So far I have this, but it only returns the first word from the list, even if it isn't the word that it found.

some advice to make this work would be appreciated.
Thanks,

```
text = 'this is a test'
words =['image', 'is']

if any(k in text for k in words):
      for k in words:
        print (k)
        print ("word found")
        break
else:
    print ("nope")
```

Comment: Remove break from for loop

Comment: Thanks for the edit yatu, I was trying to figure out how to format the code in the question.

Comment: removing break doesn't work, it just continues running until it prints out each work in the words list.

Comment: It's not about the break, the whole loop is wrong, it just prints the `words` list.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the loop `for k in words` you are simply printing all words, without checking if they are actually contained in `text`. You also need to `split` the elements in `text` to check if the resulting list contains `k`.
You want to do something like:

```
for k in words:
    if k in text.split():
        print (k)
        print ("word found")
```

**Output**

```
is
word found
```

---

The same applies to the initial condition, if you want to initially check if any words are contained in `text`, you need to split the words:

```
any(k in text.split() for k in words)
```

---

However, note that, as posted by @Austin, the most suited tool for what you're trying to do are `sets`. You can easily compute the common elements on both sets by computing the intersection as:

```
set(text.split()) & set(words)
# {'is'}
```

Find more about the topic in [sets — Unordered collections of unique elements](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Comment: Did it help @Darrenweatherall? Don't forget to upvote/accept if so, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do this (one variation among many):

```
print(", ".join(k for k in words if k in text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe restructure like this

````
text = 'this is a test'
words =['image', 'is']

words_found = [word for word in words if word in text]
if len(words_found)>0:
    print(words_found)
else:
    print("nope")

    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you are to find common elements, I would suggest to use a `set`:

```
text = 'this is a test'
words = ['image', 'is']

print(set(words).intersection(text.split()))
# {'is'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
text = 'this is a test'
words =['image', 'is']

for k in [w for w in words if w in text]: 
    print (k) 
    print ("word found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
text = 'this is a test'
words =['image', 'is']

found = False
found_words = []

for k in words:
    if k in text:
        found_words.append(k)
        found = True

if found:
    print("words found:", found_words)
else:
    print("nope")
```

Will print:

```
words found: ['is']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for i in words:
    if i in text:
        print(i)
```